# C# filtered read of several tables with multiple relations

Tags: c#, mysql, datatable, dataset, dataadapter

I have a quite large database with several tables and complex relations and thousands of records. Just to simplify the problem, say I have got a MySQL database as follows:

[table1]

- id
- table2_id
- table3_id
- name_id

[table2]

- id
- name_id

[table3]

- id
- name_id

[name]

- id
- text

Then there are relations:

- table1.name_id -> name.id
- table1.table2_id -> table2.id
- table1.table3_id -> table3.id
- table2.name_id -> name.id
- table3.name_id -> name.id

Tables contain:

- 50,000 records in table1
- 10,000 records in table2
- 5,000 records in table3
- 25,000 records in name

I need to display table1 in a DataGridView showing in columns text names.

I need a filter to be applied to every table1 request where I can include a name search keyword for each table: table1, table2, table3.

I have been trying manually fill DataSet using DataAdapters and adding DataRelations and found some problems along:

- it takes ages and a lot of memory to get DataSet filled with all the data. Obviously I do not need everything at once, I would be happy if I could limit table1 to 5,000 records with a filter applied
- considering DataAdapters and DataSets, I could not manage to set WHERE conditions to child rows in order to retrieve filtered table1 data - for example: I want to get a list of table1 where table2 name text = "a" and table3 text = "b"

I would not really want to build 'SELECT ... LEFT JOIN' or 'SELECT .... table1, table2, table3' queries as like I mentioned before, I deal with more than 6 tables with nested relations (eg. a related table is in relation with another one etc.)

I would not want to retrieve all table1 records and then filter them at C# side as like I said before - it takes a long time and there is no need to display all records on the screen. All records MUST be considered only in terms of filtering records then result can be limited to 5,000 items.

I understand using DataSet and DataAdapters may be wrong in this scenario. Any other ideas are very welcome and I am sure will be helpful as well. THANK YOU.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?